# Группировка в курсоре

Tags: mysql, процедуры

Скажите, в mysql 5, в хранимой процедуре, сделал курсор для select. А курсоры, поддерживають ли группировку в селекте?
например так:

```
declare rabota_abonent cursor for SELECT period,fio,object,time_on,monter,flat,phone_number,agrmid,catidx,agentid  from online_order group by AGRMID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Курсору все равно, какой вид имеет запрос, он обращается к уже сформированному набору.

Comment: вопрос закрыть.